# union join of kdb dictionaries having symbols as keys is working but not long keys?

Tags: dictionary, kdb, union-join

union join of KDB dictionaries having symbols as keys is working but when keys are changed to type long; dictionary join is not working?

Q code

```
k1:`1`2`3

v1: 1 2 3

k2:`2`3`4 

v2:2 3 4

//works
(enlist k1!v1) uj (enlist k2!v2)

k1:1 2 3

v1:1 2 3

k2:2 3 4 

v2:2 3 4

//not working
(enlist k1!v1) uj (enlist k2!v2)

why key list type change is not acceptable?
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that union joins can only be applied to tables. In your first example, with the column headers as symbols you are joining two tables, as shown by the type 98h:

```
k1:`1`2`3
v1: 1 2 3

type (enlist k1!v1)
98h
```

However in your second example, as the column headers are longs rather than symbols, these are actually general lists as indicated by type 0h:

```
k1: 1 2 3

type (enlist k1!v1)
0h
```

Therefore, as the arguments are not tables, uj cannot be applied.

You can read more about union joins here:
https://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/#997-union-join

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a table from a dictionary, you need to be creating [column dictionaries](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/5_Dictionaries/#53-column-dictionaries), where the keys are symbols. If you check the types of the second attempt you have dictionaries which won't join under `uj`

```
q)k1:1 2 3
q)v1:1 2 3
q).Q.qt (enlist k1!v1)
0b
```